# Bookdown 0.22 -> 0.23 :: Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: bookdown

Would anyone come across this error in rendering when upgrading from 0.22 to 0.23? It renders perfectly in 0.23 and no issues whatsoever in all the .Rmd. Looking for any cue so I can solve the problem. Linux Ubuntu R4.1.1 all packages up to date.

==> rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Execution halted
Error in Rscript_render(f, render_args, render_meta, add1, add2) :
Failed to compile index.Rmd
Calls:  ... render_book -> render_new_session -> Rscript_render
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.

Comment: The same issue  `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` on Windows 10 after updating from `bookdown`  0.22 to 0.23.

Comment: do you really mean v0.24? It seems that this version currently is not on CRAN.

Comment: I opened a related [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1238) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks @GegznaV! I confirm this fixes the issue as well. Well worth for Yihui to make this more explicit b4 a hard change.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004319/4783029) by Yihui Xie.

---

I changed the contents in `_output.yml` from

```yaml
bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
    search: yes
```

to

```yaml
bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
    search:
      engine: fuse
```

and this fixed the issue. Other options of `engine` should also work as well as total removal of line `search: yes`.

I think, the problem was related to the changes in `config` that are described [here](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/bookdown/news/index.html#new-features).

Print-screen of section of interest

[image]

Comment: This indeed fixed the issue. Recently the fuse engine can be used instad of lunr. 
it seems that if you want search to be activated you need to explicitly mention the engine

Comment: I raised an issue on github to make the issue and your solution known
https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1246

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. R 4.1.1 on OSX 11.5. Updated R packages and I get the "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" error even when rendering documents that do not contain any $ signs...

I was able to fix the issue by simply installing an older version of bookdown using:

```
library(devtools)
install_version("bookdown", version = "0.22", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Correct it works on v0.23 but does not really solve the problem (unless one is in a bind to publish). Hopefully a useful insight comes along which helps solve it. In the meantime I created new git repo using bootstrap 4 rendering.  From experience maintaining a CRAN package, it is better to ascertain it's indeed a coding issue b4 raising it on @YihuiXie github issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug of **bookdown** and [has been fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/2d977b850d7cfb698c5fd75aad91d49822734127) in the dev version, which you can install via

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```

Comment: Thank you Yihui!